# Computer connections in IIS log records

Tags: 2013, iis, logging, connection, client

Anyone knows why some of the the IIS log records of the SharePoint 2013 WFEs contain client computers' names in the `cs-username` field?

Aren't all connections supposed to be established together with **user name** information?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the field `sc-status`. IIS can only log the username if users are authenticated. You should see a username, if you have sc-status 200. You will very often see sc-status 401 which means "unauthenticated". This line will only have an IP-Address or the hostname in `cs-username`. Please note that 401 lines do not indicate any kind of error, they are a normal behavior in NTLM/Kerberos authentication.

You could also have anonymous access enabled on your WebApplication. You can check this in Central Administration -> Application Management -> Manage web applications -> mark your WebApplication -> Authentication Providers -> Default (normally) -> "Enable anonymous access".